# Problem import PrimeNG components and test with karma, schema ERROR

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, primeng

I have problem about importing primeng components in my Angular Library.
In my library I start to import (a p-message component) but when I start the karma TEST it give me the following errror.

> Error: NG0304: 'p-messages' is not a known element (used in the 'LibComponent' component template):
> 1. If 'p-messages' is an Angular component, then verify that it is a part of an @NgModule where this component is declared.
> 2. If 'p-messages' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

I do not how to fix that error,
In many forum the people resolve adding the custom SCHEMA but i do not understand why in my case that do not work.

So i try to add in the module:

```js
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'
import { LibComponent } from './lib.component';
import { InputTextModule } from 'primeng/inputtext'
import { MessagesModule } from 'primeng/messages'

@NgModule({
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  declarations: [
    LibComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    InputTextModule,
    MessagesModule
  ],
  exports: [
    LibComponent
  ]
})
export class LibModule { }
```

But i continue have the error,
So I try to add the CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA in the component

```js
import { Component, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { Message } from 'primeng/api';

@Component({
  selector: 'incas-lib',
  templateUrl: "./lib.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./lib.component.scss"],
  schemas:[CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
export class LibComponent {
  value: string | undefined;
  isOn = false;
  messages: Message[] = [{severity: "success", summary: "Success", detail: "hai avuto successo"}]
}
```

But in that case i receive the following error:

> The 'schemas' was specified for the LibComponent but is only valid on a component that is standalone.